# DAX Power Pivot measure – last previous value with where condition

Tags: dax, powerpivot, daxstudio

I am looking for a DAX measure to calculate volume = quantity * price, where the price is the last previous price for a given product.

In other words, I am looking for a DAX measure with last previous value with a "where" condition.

Take this example from the attached workbook:
I have 3 products:

- Apples
- Bananas
- Oranges

Each of these has a USD price and volume is simply quantity * price.

However, oranges can also be exchanged for apples!

To sum up the value of these orange-for-apple exchange transactions with the other USD transactions, I first need to calculate the USD value of the oranges, and for this I need to know the last price paid for an apple, i.e. last previous price, where product = apple.

Take this example from the attached workbook:

- The last previous price paid for an apple was USD 5
- The total USD price (volume) for 10 apples sold is: 10*50= USD50
- Subsequently 3 oranges were exchanged for apples, at a rate of 4 apples per orange
- The total USD price (volume) for 3 oranges is: 3x4x5= USD60, i.e. # number of oranges * ratio oranges to apples * last previous price for an apple
- Total transaction volume = 50 + 60 = USD 110

There are a few more examples in this sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PTaKg9a3Yv1um2RTnpeYC4gdLVjQXEzl/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106440602605717108817&rtpof=true&sd=true

What I am looking for is a DAX formula that gives me the last previous value with a condition or filter or where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The following works as a calculated column, but is expensive, because it uses EARLIER:

```
=
VAR Conditional_Volume = IF(Transactions[product] = "orange_apple",
    CALCULATE(
    MAX(Transactions[price]), 
    ALL(Transactions),
    (Transactions[product]="apple"),    
    Transactions[transaction_id] < EARLIER(Transactions[transaction_id])
)*Transactions[price]*Transactions[quantity],Transactions[price]*Transactions[quantity])
RETURN Conditional_Volume
```